# The rank of the product of the upper triangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are $n$-square upper-triangular matrices for which all diagonal entries are zeros and $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(B)=n-1$, then $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=n-2$.

How can this be proved?

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: show that rank(AB)=n-1

Comment: The statement is not correct: take $A=\text{diag}(1,1,0)$ and $B=A= \text{diag}(1,1,0)$. Both are upper-triangular and have rank $3-1=2$ but their product also has rank $2$. If you take $B=\text{diag}(0,1,1)$ instead you get rank $1$ for the product. A general statement on the rank of $AB$ under the given assumptions can't be made.

Comment: with diagonal entries equal zero!

Comment: all diagonal entries of both $A$ and $B$ are zeros?

Comment: The Question, at least as @kabenyuk rephrased it, does present a problem that can be resolved by reasoned mathematical argument. However the Question, even with that edit, lacks context.  Please allow the Original Poster to supply the motivation or research behind the problem.  I am voting to close, but will happily reconsider once that edit is done.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints.**

1. If $\operatorname{rank}(A)=n-1$, then $\operatorname{dim}A(W)\geq\operatorname{dim}W -1$ for each subspace $W$ of $V$.
2. Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be the standard basis of the space $V$. We have $A(v_i)$ and $B(v_i)$ are linear combinations of vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_{i-1}$ for all $i>1$ and $A(v_1)=B(v_1)=0$.
3. Since $\operatorname{rank}(B)=n-1$ from 2 it follows, that $B(V)=W=\langle v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}\rangle$.
4. It is clear, that $A(W)\leq\langle v_1,\ldots,v_{n-2}\rangle$. So $\operatorname{dim}AB(V)\leq n-2$ and from 1 it follows that $\operatorname{dim}AB(V)\geq n-2$.

Comment: Please do not answer questions that don't meet the [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).